# insert or update on table "Users" violates foreign key constraint "Users_LocalUnit_fkey"

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have to tables: `Users` and `LocalUnits`. I created a foreign key of `localunit` in `Users`, did a migration, everything ok.

When I tried to update the database I got this error:

> 23503: insert or update on table "Users" violates foreign key constraint "Users_LocalUnit_fkey"

Here is my code:

```
entity.Property(e => e.IdLocalUnit)
    .HasColumnName("local_unit_id");

entity.HasOne(e=>e.IdLocalUnitNavigation)
    .WithMany(p => p.Users)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdLocalUnit)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
    .HasConstraintName("Users_LocalUnit_fkey")
```

I must tell you that the `local_unit_id` column doesn't yet exist in the `User` table. I tried to apply a migration of the `User`'s table in order to create the `local_unit_id` column but I couldn't, I got this error:

> 42701: column "is_registered_office" of relation "LocalUnits" already exists

which is true and I do not know how to do.